# Magento attaching javascript but not running any functions(message undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am currently using magneto for one of the first times, and I am attempting to make a slideshow specifically for the homepage. My code is displayed in the source code and my browsers debugger, but all the functions when say undefined.

I have tried to both put my JavaScript through the page content on the CMS, and also externally by using an Layout Update XML which goes:

```
<reference name="head">

<action method="addItem">
<type>skin_js</type><script>Homepage.js</script>
</action>
</reference>
```

My javascript code in  homepage.js is

```
var ImgNumber = 5; // the number of slides, all slides should be be named "slide" + the dedicated slide number. etc slide1, slide2, slide3, and they should be in jpg.
var CurrentSlide = 1; //the starting slide. 
var slidewidth = 983 * ImgNumber;
slidewidth = slidewidth+"px"; 
var SlideTimer;
$('#jsSlideimageholder').css('width', slidewidth);


ChangeHomeShow();


function ChangeHomeShow(){
if(CurrentSlide == ImgNumber){
CurrentSlide = 1;
}

//To great the move. 
Var MinusOurSlideNumber = CurrentSlide - 1;
var tmpSlideNumber  = MinusOurSlideNumber * 983; //will come 0 if 1

//now for the animation. 

$('#HomepagejsSlideshow').animate({
position: 'relative',
left: tmpSlideNumber,
}, 2000);

}
function StartTimer(){
//SlideTimer = setInterval(functrion() {ChangeHomeShow()}, 8000);
alert('hate magento');
}

function StopTimer(){
clearInterval(SlideTimer);
}
```

My given error from chrome is ChangeHomeShow() is not defined. Same goes for StartTimer() and StopTimer().

Any advice?

I appreciate it.

Comment: Don't you have a jQuery conflict ? 
Try to use jQuery.noConflict and in the Homepage.js replace $ by jQuery

Comment: Helo. Thank you for the tip, I tried to use the jQuery.noConflict method and replaced all $ with jQuery, however unfortunately it didnt fix the issue

Comment: Have you it live ? Have you an url to let me see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
ChangeHomeShow();

function ChangeHomeShow(){
    if(CurrentSlide == ImgNumber){
    CurrentSlide = 1;
}
```

To

```
function ChangeHomeShow(){
    if(CurrentSlide == ImgNumber){
    CurrentSlide = 1;
}


ChangeHomeShow();
```

All your functions need to be define before you can calling it (or you could use http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Sorry only really new here, i will do,